# Сложности с запросом к БД

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Есть запрос. Куда мне вставить функцию sql COUNT(*)?

```
    mysql_query("SELECT datacenter.name, datacenter.surname, senderInfo.name_avatar, senderInfo.has_avatar FROM datacenter LEFT JOIN photo AS senderInfo ON datacenter.id = senderInfo.id  WHERE datacenter.id_s = '$id_s' AND datacenter.type = '$touch' ")
```

Comment: Поподробнее бы. количество чего тебе нужно узнать, для начала?

Comment: количество id

Comment: У тебя же 2 таблицы. Уточни. datacenter.id || photo.id?

Comment: Виталий Кустов
вообще мне надо посчитать, сколько строк вернул запрос

Comment: datacenter.id это первичный ключ

Comment: Ёхараный бабай прав. Не смог ответить ибо надо было бежать. А Вам совет: яснее выражайте свои мысли. При чем здесь count, если Вам на деле совсем другое нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю количество id  -это количество найденных строк запросом. Тогда обычный mysql_num_rows(); Если првильно понял вопрос. Уточните детали.

Answer (score 0):

Вспомнился анекдот о поручике Ржевском, подсвечнике о трех свечах и четвертой свечке.
Сам удивляюсь, к чему это.